# Get Isset Variable to Specific Value

Tags: php, if-statement

```php
if (isset($data['start']['tan']) AND $data['start']['tan'] == true) {
    $get_data[] = 'tan';
}

if (isset($data['start']['ban']) AND $data['start']['ban'] == true) {
    $get_data[] = 'ban';
}

if (isset($data['start']['pan']) AND $data['start']['pan'] == true) {
    $get_data[] = 'pan';
}
```

Try to take only `tan` equal to `"a111"` values. Tested the code below, but I could not get even `tan` values.

```php
if (isset($data['start']['tan']) AND $data['start']['tan'] == true AND $data['start']['tan'] == 'a111') {
    $get_data[] = 'tan';
}
```

Comment: how can `$data['start']['tan']` be **true** AND **a111**

Comment: @tim sure it can https://3v4l.org/PgD2N

Comment: @Andreas this is why php is a joke.

Comment: @tim if you only know how to use PHP, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug this yourself?  Is it possible that the data you are looking for is not in the $data variable?  Or that it's in a different format?

Try adding this:

```
print_r($data)
```

before your IF statements to help you debug the issue.  Your code MOSTLY looks correct.  Though, I know that I have always used .= when potentially appending to arrays, instead of just = .  Like:

```
$get_data=array();

if ($tan) $get_data[] .= $data;
```

Of course, I was generalizing in my above example, but you get the idea.